# Sequence used to increment and ID in Postgresql not called by hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I added a sequence *MAIL_ID_SEQ* to an existing table in Postgresql :

```
CREATE SEQUENCE MAIL_ID_SEQ START WITH 1;
alter table MAIL alter column ID set default nextval('MAIL_ID_SEQ'::regclass);
alter SEQUENCE MAIL_ID_SEQ owned by MAIL.ID;
```

The ID exist inside a composite key MailId :

```
@Embeddable
public class MailId implements Serializable{
  @Column(name = "ID")
  private int id;

  @Column(name = "YEAR")
  private int year;
}
```

I want the ID to be *auto_increment* using the sequence I created.
The problem is that the value of the ID is always 0 when a new record is inserted from via **Hibernate**, but when I insert a value directly from the command line (`inset into  MAIL ..`) in the MAIL table, the value of the ID is incremented.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my answer, it seems that I misunderstood the issue you're having.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add annotations like this to the `id` field:

```
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "mail_id_gen", sequenceName = "MAIL_ID_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "mail_id_gen")
```

The generator name must be different for each class. The `allocationSize` is completely optional, but setting it to 1 is a workaround to a bug in Hibernate 5.0 and 5.1 related to sequences not created by schema export. Another workaround for that bug is to set the `hibernate.id.optimizer.pooled.preferred` property to `NONE` in the `persistence.xml` like this:

```
<property name="hibernate.id.optimizer.pooled.preferred" value="NONE"/>
```

If this is not enough and it still tries to insert 0, change the field type from `int` to `Integer` and leave it's default to `null`.

Comment: Thanks for you answer , I'm using hibernate 4.3. The only turnaround that worked for me is to add and SqlQuery  as : `getSession().createSQLQuery("select nextval('courrier_id_seq')");` and set the result manually the to id.

Comment: Our project also uses 4.3. A modified version with one little optimization for us. Unrelated to it, all of our entities have the `@SequenceGenerator` and `@GeneratedValue` annotations appropriately to work. A `@GeneratedValue` alone with default parameters might also work, but it's a style we've inherited. Having tables or sequences that are not entirely lower-cased has some times caused bugs with Hibernate + Postgre.